How can I manually allow Local Network access for an app?
An app I use (barrier) does not request Local Network access. I would like to manually give it access because it currently is not able to connect to another machine on my network. Can I assign this permission manually somehow?
Note, the app does not show up in the Settings > Privacy & Security > Local Network screen.

Local Network Privacy is new in Sequoia. The developer would have to update the app with a "multicast entitlement" so that it can be granted access by the user. You can't do it yourself.
Local Network Privacy FAQ-3 (developer.apple.com)

This is going to be a tough transition for those of us who are using apps that are no longer maintained

Why not run an older macOS virtually and then you just have to make sure the virtualization engine has this entitlement @JoePhillips ?
