X11 Forwarding on Sequoia
I am trying to get x11 forwarding to work on my new MacBook Air. I have installed the latest xQuartz.
I am running this scenario from a non administrator account.

launch xQuartz
from a terminal , I ssh to a server ie. ssh -X user@server-ip

I have also used -Y in the scenario, but it doesn't help. I am able to ssh to the server-ip, so that itself is not a problem.
I have set this up before but I can't remember if there is an extra detail that I have missed like making a setting modification in the network area of the control settings.
I have read some stuff about making modifications to the .ssh/config file that would turn on x11 forwarding, but I have also read many other items that state that doing that isnt' necessary if you use the -X -Y switch.
Any help will be appreciated !

Does this discussion about local network access on Sequoia answer the question?  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/476030/no-route-to-host-on-iterm2-only ?  The concept is the same, but does X11 appear in the Settings to give it such access?

Thanks @MarcWilson. I don't think it is related. I can ssh to the remote server. I can't x11 forward from the remote server. Thanks for trying to help, nevertheless.

Deleted my own stupid comment.  Of course forwarding X is an inbound connection to the Mac over the tunnel.
